# Returns key and value of a localstorage object

Tags: typescript, local-storage

I get a localstorage built like this:

```
  TYPE_MAPPING  : {"type":{"B2B":"B2B","UNKNOWN":"B2C","blabla":"B2C"}}
```

when I want to retrieve the key and value from localstorage

```
  const type = localStorage.getItem(TYPE_MAPPING);

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(type)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
   }
```

I get the following error message :

```
  TS2769: No overload matches this call.   
  Overload 1 of 2, '(o: { [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike<string>): [string, string][]', gave the following error.     
  Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike<string>'.       
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ [s: string]: string; } | ArrayLike<string>'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(o: {}): [string, any][]', gave the following error.     
  Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type '{}'.       Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{}'.
```

what would be the solution to recover the keys and values of the localStorage ?

Comment: That's a TypeScript error, not JavaScript.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem()` returns a string. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening with the console.log line and the values it's getting are null values.  I'd guess the problem is with the Object.entries(type) call not getting values for you.  And it might be the variable name... type is a reserved word in a lot of languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**localstorage.getItem** return a string, so you have to parse it before
```

```js
  const type = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(TYPE_MAPPING));

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(type)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type object you're trying to get is nested in the type variable. Try this:

```
const type = localStorage.getItem(TYPE_MAPPING);

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(type.type)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```